# LetsEncrypt Challenge failed for domain

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, lets-encrypt, certbot, crt

Running this with my domain:

```
sudo certbot certonly --standalone --preferred-challenges http --server https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory --register-unsafely-without-email -d example.com

Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator standalone, Installer None
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for example.com
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain example.com
http-01 challenge for example.com
Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: exxample.com
   Type:   connection
   Detail: correct.ip.address: Fetching
   http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/jHPVDWvcICxX0vt7auklR1vR8osXbSOEqbidqE7JmcE:
   Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
   your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
   firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
   client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
   that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.
```

Note: Without using `--standalone` I am able to download the file `wget http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/8SPcqxypfvqpVz-koSWJxesGw4HuSOD84J6k5xnFPZ0`

I have port forward working correct and in the Ubuntu server I did `ufw 80` and `ufw 443`. But still note, that I am able to wget the file manually.

I have ipv4 records, but no AAAA ipv6 records - but I guess it should work with ipv4.

And I have no problem serving `pyton3 -m http.server 80` and curl to the server.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you curl that file from outside that server?

Comment: Yes, if I do it without --standalone and serve the file with python3 -m http.server I can downloiad the file with wget

Comment: Have you updated the DNS records recently? Could it be a cache issue?

Comment: Good question, but no changes recently. Also I can curl and wget using domain.

Comment: I have ipv4 records, but no AAAA ipv6 records

Comment: If you are having these issues, consider getting the certificate with Lets Encrypt via DNS.

Comment: Thank, but I need this to be an easy setup via local script - for test servers

Comment: Just so you know, I guess its simpler. Instead of worrying about firewalls you just need that your DNS provider provide an API. Everything else remains almost the same. Its easier and simpler, at least for me.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks - I will have a look